# Alternative to MSM?

Tags: multi-site-manager, datagrab, json

We're running several big sites on a MSM install, but we're finding it's becoming increasingly difficult to upgrade one site without breaking another. It's just become a tangled mess actually and we're also concerned about the ballooning size of the database as we opened up a user loyalty component to one of the sites.

Our only thought is to break each site into its own EE install, but how do still share posts across sites? JSON feed from one site with a Datagrab cron job on the other site? Any one have experience with a set up like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a tricky one, but i would check out [Open Api](http://www.putyourlightson.net/open-api) which is a nice api in which to perform CRUD operations, you might run into some cross-site ajax issues though, but it can definitely be done.

Comment: Or the Entry Api (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-api)